# Turn "responsive grids" in carousel when < 750px

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a grid like this:

- In Desktop/tablets (750px or more):

  [image: grid no desktop or tablets]
- In mobiles (< 750px):

  [image: grid em um celular]
- But I need turn grids in a carousel when the display is less than 750px:

  [image: grid turn in carousel/slider]

My current code:

```
<section>
    <h2 class="section-heading text-center">Lançamentos</h2>
    <hr class="primary">
    <div class="row nospace">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/produto1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <h3>Produto</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/produto2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <h3>Produto</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/produto3.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <h3>Produto</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/produto4.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <h3>Produto</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

How to do this using bootstrap?

Comment: I was missing a pretty important div, I updated the answer with a updated fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Use a media query to hide your div gallery and show a bootstrap carousel (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) when below 750px using a media query: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

If you can't figure it out let me know and I'll help you through it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the effect you are going for https://jsfiddle.net/4khoydbe/3/

I used a carasual that is hidden, and at `770px` using a media query it becomes visible.

```
#mobile{display: none}
@media (max-width: 770px){
   #mobile{display: inline} 
   .desktop{display: none} 
}
```

I change to 770px so the page doesn't break, however when you use your own pictures you can probably set it back to 750px.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento I was missing a div sorry, here it is working https://jsfiddle.net/4khoydbe/3/

Answer (score 1):

After trying almost an hour for plugin. I fixed this using below approach.

- Used bootstrap carousel with `data-interval="false"` to stop auto rotation.
- Used media query to `dislpay: block` slides above `768px`

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .mobileSlider .carousel-item {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="mobileCarousel" class="carousel slide mobileSlider" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators d-md-none">
    <li data-target="#mobileCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#mobileCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#mobileCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="carousel-item active col-md-4">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="d-md-none carousel-control-prev" href="#mobileCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="d-md-none carousel-control-next" href="#mobileCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is really awesome in bootstrap 4 but I want to do it in BS-5
Please share some more example here..